# Bat para ordenar ficheros

Tags: .bat, ordenar

Necesito crear un bat para organizar ficheros, el caso es que tengo dentro una carpeta multiples ficheros con mismo nombre y diferente extensión, quisiera crear carpetas con el nombre comun de cada archivo y moverlos a su carpeta común, y así queden todos los archivos con mismo nombre y diferente extensión dentro de una carpeta
He intentado crear las carpetas desde una lista creada pero el leer las extensiones no las crea correctamente

Answer (score 0):

Este script `Batch` utiliza una variable **dir** para especificar la ruta de la carpeta donde están los archivos a organizar. La variable **name** contiene el nombre común de los archivos. El script itera sobre todos los archivos en la carpeta especificada y crea una carpeta con el nombre común de los archivos y mueve los archivos a esa carpeta.

Si estás usando windos el script sería así:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "dir=C:\ruta\a\la\carpeta\donde\estan\los\archivos"
set "name=nombre_comun_de_los_archivos"

for %%a in ("%dir%\*%name%*.*") do (
    set "ext=%%~xa"
    set "folder=%%~na"
    set "folder=!folder:~0,-1!"
    mkdir "%dir%\!!folder!!%name!!"
    move "%%a" "%dir%\!!folder!!%name!!%ext!"
)
```

Si estás usando Linux sería:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir="ruta/a/la/carpeta/donde/estan/los/archivos"
name="nombre_comun_de_los_archivos"

for file in "$dir"/*"$name"*
do
    ext="${file##*.}"
    folder="${file%.*}"
    folder="${folder%/*}"
    folder="${folder:0:(-1)}"
    mkdir -p "$dir/$folder/$name"
    mv "$file" "$dir/$folder/$name/$name.$ext"
done
```